# Flex 4 - How to use filter for NumericStepper?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an XML file Which contains Employee details . And I have to use filter on it. Here, I want to filter the experience using two NumericStepper. If I select 1 and 4 for first and second NumericStepper,  DataGrid Will display the employee list which are the employee's has experienced between 1 to 4.

Here my code:

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        private function xmlListCollectionFilterFun(item : Object) : Boolean
        {
            if(employeeName.text.length !=0)
            {
                if((item.Name).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeName.text.toLowerCase())!= -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if(employeeID.text.length != 0)
            {
                if((item.Id).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeID.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            if(endYear.value != 0)
            {
                if((startYear.value)<=(item.Experience)<=(endYear.value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            } 

            return false;
        }

        protected function employeeText_changeHandler():void
        {
            if( employeeName.text.length == 0 && endYear.value == 0 &&
                employeeID.text.length == 0 )
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = null;
            }
            else
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = xmlListCollectionFilterFun;
            }
            employeeXMLList.refresh();

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>

    <fx:XML id="tempXML"
            source="skins/TextXmlFile.xml" />

    <s:XMLListCollection id="employeeXMLList"
                         source="{tempXML.Employee}" filterFunction="xmlListCollectionFilterFun"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="30"/>
</s:layout>
<mx:VBox width="100%">
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:TextInput id="employeeName" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" prompt="Employee Name"/>
        <s:TextInput id="employeeID" prompt="Employee ID" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"/>
        <s:NumericStepper id="startYear" minimum="0" maximum="50" snapInterval="1" />
        <s:NumericStepper id="endYear" minimum="0" maximum="50" snapInterval="1" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeXMLList}" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn id="nameCol" dataField="Name" headerText="Name:"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="idCol" dataField="Id" headerText="ID:"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="experienceCol" dataField="Experience" headerText="Experience:"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
```

This is code is no effect for NumericStepper. If anyone can find my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try always to split your code in small functions that do a single thing, I would do it like this:

```
 getUserExperience(user:Object):Number
```

implement this function first do some test and after you get it o return the correct experience then you can go to the next step to make the filter function.

Write some code to compute the min and max experience for the filter

```
var min:Number=startYear.value;
var max:Number=endYear.value;//if needed adjust this to seome default values
```

now the filtering should be easy because you just have numbers and no UI components and Objects
so the filter will need to check a simple thing

```
var userExp:Number=getUserExperience(user);
var response:Boolean=mio<=userExp&&userExp<=max;

return response;
```

I am sure after you refactor your code to be simple and clear it will be easy to fix any bugs

Comment: yes.. It's right. Thank you so much simion. I think your tip will helpful for my career too. I got answer. Again thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo in your code or a problem with stack overflow that doesn't display some chars (the OR pipes I assume) ?

```
employeeName.text.length == 0 endYear.value == 0 &&
            employeeID.text.length == 0
```

update: even with pipes, this test does not make sense.